# why did Doc Brown's delightful April Fools' post disappear?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I came across the amazing and delightful post by Doc E Brown regarding his "chrononaut transporter machine". But today the post is gone. Vanished. Poof. Gone to the big 404 graveyard.

Here is the former URL, all that remains to preserve for posterity. Sigh.

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/what-appearance-should-my-chrononaut-transporter-machine-take

Was it really voluntarily removed by the author? Or was there some coercion involved?
What's wrong with some easter eggs sprinkled on the site now and then?

Comment: A paradox appears to have erased the question

Comment: i think the space time continuum was interrupted.  That the open day of the 2013 baseball season was on the 31st might have something to do with it.

Comment: You can see the post in the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8778883#8778883) here and in [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GCVgRPKofYQJ:ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/what-appearance-should-my-chrononaut-transporter-machine-take+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in) here. And thanks for posting because I don't frequent here and really loved the Fools post!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the good Doctor (oh wait, that's Dr Who...) I mean 'Doc' only popped by for a brief period while the space-time continuum alignments were in... alignment. Co-incidentally this happened on April 1st for some reason.

Actually, I think that as he was discussing time travel technology there is the possibility that we were actually viewing a version of ux.StackExchange *from the future* hence why it's not visible today? Perhaps you'll have to wait until the year 2025 for it to actually appear?!?

There are still some 'interesting' posts on the site though that weren't posted by a crazy doctor from the future though; try out the [Is this rotating cube interface user-friendly?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-this-rotating-cube-interface-user-friendly) for good measure.

Comment: That rotating cube does reduce real estate requirements of a web page, yet its time inversion leaves me aghast: the faster it spins the longer it takes to fill out completely!

Answer (score 4):

You can find an [image of the post here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk4WL.jpg) which was posted [in Chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8778883#8778883)

Comment: This is phenomenal.